# How do I enable the title bar to be shown in my iTerm2 window?

Tags: iterm2

I was playing around with preferences, and now my new windows don't have a title bar.  How can I show the title bar again?

[image: screenshot of no title bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Window > Settings for New Windows > Style > Normal

Instead of `Normal` style, I had selected `Full-Height Right of Screen`, which caused the window take up the full height of the screen, and not have a title bar.

[[image: screenshot of iterm2 preferences] [[image: screenshot showing title bar]Profiles

Answer (score 1):

I found your question before searching led me to the answer in the iTerm2 docs, but your answer did not apply to my case. So here is another possible answer for others who might be looking in the future (likely myself 2 years from now).

In my case, I had selected the "Minimal" or "Compact" theme at some point in the past, whereas what I really wanted was "Normal" and to rely on fullscreen to hide the title bar when I am working only on my laptop's screen.

From the [docs](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-appearance.html) (my emphasis):

> On macOS 10.14 and later, there are two additional options:
>
> - Regular - The standard macOS theme. Switches between dark and light
>   mode automatically based on the system setting.
> - Minimal - This is inspired by the appearance of Electron apps. It is modern and streamlined.
> - Compact - A combination of Regular and Minimal. The
>   standard colors are used, but the **title bar is eliminated** to save
>   space.

It is impossible to find in the application's UI itself by searching for "title bar", because "title bar" appears nowhere in this view or list of values, although it is mentioned in a number of places.

[image: iTerm2 Preferences - Appearance]

Comment: I hunted high and low because I set up my iTerm a long time ago with the Quake style sliding screen. But when I wanted a normal term session, I couldn't figure out for the life of me why I was not getting the title bar. I was using the Normal Window but no luck. Thanks for saving my sanity!